# iOS Blank White Space at bottom of viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

A strange white space appears at the bottom of a viewcontroller sometimes it disappear.

White space hides a button at the bottom left.

[image]

[image]

Please, help me out, I've searched a lot only thing I came across is

```
  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

But it's not working
Thanks

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: @ozd No I am not using it

Comment: r u using tabbar view controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen due to either of the two reasons
1. Another view is overlapping your view
2. Height for your view is not enough to contain all the contents and view.clipsToBounds is set to Yes.

View debugging option in Xcode can show you what is happening.
Reproduce the issue in simulator and press the 'debug view hierarchy' button in Xcode. Xcode will render a 3D model of the view hierarchy which you can view from any angle by moving the model around with mouse. Click on any point on the model and Xcode will tell you what view it is and you can identify the overlapping view.